# Flutter Provider: Lifespan and Intended Use

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have an app that has multiple screens which display the Users current XP and other in-game achievements.
At first I was using static variables (that would re-update from Firebase if they got wiped by the OS), then I switched to passing the User object between screens and then I finally realized there are many other problems like data not updating on **Navigator.pop()** and similar.

I then switched to using the **Provider Package**. It works wonderfuly, although I'm sure I don't understand half of the code that comes with Provider.

Now I'm becoming paranoid if this is good use of the Provider and what is the lifespan of the provider class?
I wrapped **MyApp** in **ChangeNotifierProvider** of <**UserData**> and intend to use the data inside until the VM is terminated - will data be retained inside the provider class for that long?

Simple code example:

```
Class UserData extends ChangeNotifier {
    String _UID;
    int _highscore;
    
    void updateHighscore(int i) {
        _highscore += i;
        notifyListeners();
    }
    
    String getUserID() {
        return _UID;
    }

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the data doesn't slowly fade away like radioactive decay.  So as long as you keep the right things in scope, it should be fine.

Comment: Could you please expand on "keeping the right things in scope"? Android will clean your static variables, so data sometimes does fade away.